# Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of invalid platform response (with Youtube API)

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am trying to build a YouTube entertainment app using Google Assistant, following this tutorial: [here](https://medium.com/voice-tech-podcast/build-a-youtube-entertainment-app-with-google-assistant-9b5793b04473). I have followed every step precisely, copying code verbatim, but when I run the test, I get this error:

> MalformedResponse Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of invalid platform response: Could not find a RichResponse or SystemIntent in the platform response for agentId: ~~ and intentId: ~~. WebhookStatus: code: 2 message: "Webhook call failed. Error: UNKNOWN." ..

I'm not really well versed in DialogFlow, so I'm not sure what's happening. If anyone has any advice, I'd really appreciate it!

Edit: So, here's what happens that triggers the error. I follow the tutorial all the way to the end. I run the test and type in their test request 'rahman'. The response I get back from the test is the above error. I'm not sure what other details I can add, but if there's anything else I can provide, please let me know!

Edit 2: Following the next comment I received, I opened the cloud functions up in the GCP console and found that a new function was made called dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment. I checked the logs for the 'youtube' function I made, and found this notification:

```
 {
 insertId: "..."  

labels: {
  execution_id: ""   
 }
 logName: "projects/<name of project>/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions"  
 receiveTimestamp: "<time>"  

resource: {

labels: {…}   
  type: "cloud_function"   
 }
 severity: "ERROR"  
 textPayload: "Warning, estimating Firebase Config based on GCLOUD_PROJECT. Intializing firebase-admin may fail"  
 timestamp: "<time>"  
}
```

I then checked out the new function that was made without me knowing and saw it didn't deploy, having an error: "Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Node.js module defined by file index.js is expected to export function named dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment". I checked the logs and found this:

```
 {
 insertId: "<id>"  
 logName: "projects/<project name>/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity"  

operation: {
  id: "operations/<id>"   
  last: true   
  producer: "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com"   
 }

protoPayload: {
  @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog"   

authenticationInfo: {
   principalEmail: "<email>"    
  }
  methodName: "google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction"   

requestMetadata: {

destinationAttributes: {
   }

requestAttributes: {
   }
  }
  resourceName: "projects/<project name>/locations/us-central1/functions/dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment"   
  serviceName: "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com"   

status: {
   code: 3    
   message: "INVALID_ARGUMENT"    
  }
 }
 receiveTimestamp: "<time>"  

resource: {

labels: {…}   
  type: "cloud_function"   
 }
 severity: "ERROR"  
 timestamp: "<time>"
```

I know this isn't a good sign, but I also don't know how to really interpret where I should go fix the error. Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! There are a number of possible causes of the problem, and it is difficult to diagnose without more information. If you can update your question to show the detailed logs from the GCP function, along with exactly what you said that triggered the error, we may be able to help you narrow down the problem.

Comment: Oh, sure! I'll try my best.

Comment: That error looks like it appears in the Action test tool. When you entered your function into the CGP console, there should also be a way to view errors that appear during execution of the function. Those errors should give more information about why the code either wasn't executed or crashed during execution.

Comment: Hi! I updated the post, so commenting here to make sure it gets noticed.